# Why do my interface elements keep appearing off-screen?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5.5

I'm developing a mobile app, so I want to test my application by pressing control+enter.  When my swf file appears, some interface elements are off-screen. Maximizing the window doesn't help, but if I test scene, it works well.

[image]

Comment: The real test is on device. Don't try to fix a code if you are testing it in the wrong conditions.

Comment: How is file size related to this screenshot and interface problem? If you are trying to fit window to your monitor, maybe you can change your stage settings. Your monitor cannot emulate 480x800.

Comment: Just increase your  computer screen resolution from the control panel

Comment: Also you could try click+dragging the corners to re-size the preview window?